# How to regain sudo permissions?

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo, root

I'm using WSL1 and at some point I did something that means I can no longer use the 'sudo' command at all (unfortunately, I can't remember what I did or when that caused this issue but it definitely used to work – I'm very new to all this, so apologies!).

When I run anything beginning with 'sudo' I get the following errors:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've spent a while looking for solutions but nothing seems to work so far. E.g. I've tried using

```
pkexec visudo
```

But anything like that throws this error:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

I saw another thread that suggested going into the Windows command line and entering the following:

```
wsl -u root
```

But that simply returns

```
User not found.
```

Is there any way to get back my sudo permissions or have I done something that's unsalvageable, requiring me to uninstall WSL and start again? Thanks.

**Further info**
Thanks all for your answers. It's looking I will have to wipe WSL and start over (teaches me not to mess with things I don't understand!).
@NotTheDr01ds – you asked what cat /etc/passwd, and stat /etc/passwd show. cat /etc/passwd shows the following

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash                                                                                         daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                         bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                                    sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                                    sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync                                                                                      games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                         man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                         lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                            mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                             news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                       uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                     proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                              www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                    backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                    list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                           irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                        gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin                                       nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                              systemd-network:x:100:102:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/usr/sbin/nologin                            systemd-resolve:x:101:103:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/usr/sbin/nologin                                    syslog:x:102:106::/home/syslog:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                        messagebus:x:103:107::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                    _apt:x:104:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                        lxd:x:105:65534::/var/lib/lxd/:/bin/false                                                                               uuidd:x:106:110::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                           dnsmasq:x:107:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                          landscape:x:108:112::/var/lib/landscape:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                               sshd:x:109:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin                                                                           pollinate:x:110:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false                                                                      peterjatkinson:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/peterjatkinson:/bin/bash

While stat /etc/passwd shows:

> File: /etc/passwd                                                                                                       Size: 1574            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 512    regular file                                                Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 7036874417973417  Links: 1                                                                       Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/peterjatkinson)   Gid: (    0/    root)                                          Access: 2020-07-12 10:01:59.045006400 +0100                                                                             Modify: 2020-07-12 10:01:59.045800500 +0100                                                                             Change: 2021-07-20 17:26:32.778110500 +0100                                                                              Birth: -

If that gleans anything useful that might help save me from reinstalling WSL, then please do let me know! Thanks again.

Comment: It may be faster to just wipe the WSL distribution. I assume you can still access/backup whatever data you saved there?

Comment: Try: `pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R`.

Comment: @harrymc To my knowledge, `pkexec` won't work under WSL1, will it?  Not sure about WSLg, but that would be WSL2.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: Just tried and you're right - `pkexec` is not supported in WSL1.

Comment: Missed the part about `wsl -u root` not working.  Agree with harrymc and danielb -- Probably going to require a reinstall.  Just curious, though - What's `cat /etc/passwd` and `stat /etc/passwd` show?  I'm guessing that it may be owned by UID 1000 as well?  That could cause the `wsl -u root` failure, but if that's the case, I can't think of any way to recover :-(

Comment: Considering this is WSL1, I have a feeling that you may have, at some point, accessed files on the `rootfs` from within Windows, causing [corruption](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).  There are other things that could have caused the issue, but that seems most likely given the unexpected change in ownership of `/etc/sudoers`.  Doing something like recursively changing your *Windows* permissions under %AppData% could have even inadvertently caused the corruption.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I've added a bit more info requested by NotTheDr01ds. But if still stuck I'll just have to delete WSL and start again.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried `pkexec` in WSL1 and got exactly the same error as you,
so `pkexec` is just not supported in WSL1.

But `wsl -u root` works fine for me, without the message of
"User not found".

This message means that you have somehow corrupted the user list,
or changed permissions on some crucial system files.
It would be next to impossible to analyze the problem, especially since
`root` seems inaccessible.

I join my voice to DanielB, in suggesting that you delete this
WSL distribution and start from scratch.

To properly delete an installed Linux distro from disk,
go into the Windows
*Settings > Apps section > Apps & features*,
scroll down to your distribution,
click on it and then on the now displayed "Uninstall" button.

Comment: Also, I just tried it in WSL2, and it doesn't seem to be supported there either, at least not without X running or WSLg.  Also see [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/6178#discussioncomment-117848).